# C#: Convert a string to an object reference

Tags: c#, types, casting

Basically a button's tag property is the name of an existing combobox which I need to dynamically reference. It's a generic function to handle multiple buttons. Help

```
private void SQLButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    magic(((Button)sender).Tag.ToString());
}

private void magic(string currentcombo)
{
    string CurrentText = (ComboBox).(currentcombo).Text;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the Tag property to the actual ComboBox and avoid your problem altogether.

```
//code when defining your button...
{
     sqlButton.Tag = comboBoxA;  //instead of comboBoxA.Name
}

private void SQLButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    ComboBox comboBox = button.Tag as ComboBox;

    if (comboBox == null ) 
    {...}
    else
    {
        magic(comboBox);
    }
}

private void magic(ComboBox currentcombo)
{
    string CurrentText = currentcombo.Text;
}
```

Comment: how do I do that?, that seems to be an interesting approach.

Comment: Tag can be anything.  So when you set the Tag of your button to comboBoxA.Name just use comboBoxA instead.

Comment: So I can use comboBoxA.Text and that will retrieve the current contents and pass it on to the method;
private void SQLButton(object sender, EventArgs e){    magic(((Button)sender).Tag);}

Comment: thanks,
this.button1.Tag = sourceComboBox.Text;
Simple Solution

Answer (score 4):

I *think* I understand what you're after -

You'll want to change your "magic" routine to something like:

```
private void magic(string currentCombo) {
    ComboBox box = this.Controls.Find(currentCombo) as ComboBox;
    if(box != null) {
        // You can do your "work" here...
        string currentText = box.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be a (ComboBox)-cast instead of using as ... you don't want to get a NullRef-exception instead of a Cast-exception

Comment: I prefer this way, personally.  I added a null check for you, though.

Comment: Yeah, with null-check I like it more, too :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the string id value of a control then you can use FindControl to get a reference to the control.

Something like ...

```
Button btn = (Button)FindControl("some_id");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its winforms or asp.net. I am assuming it to be winforms

You could use `this.Controls(theNameofTheControl)` instead of magic.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Controls.Find Method, to get the instance of the Control using the name.

Answer (score 0):

If currentcombo paramter in magic function is the identifier for the control you are going to change then use Page's function FindControl:

```
string CurrentText = ((ComboBox)FindControl(currentcombo)).Text;
```

Page.FindControl() method searches the page naming container for a server control with the specified identifier.

Comment: FindControl doest not exist in the curren context? (am I missing a reference?
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;